# "realtime" ratingbar indicator in Flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, ratingbar

I’m new to Flutter and programming in general, so maybe my question is stupid, 
but I need some help. On my app I have a screen with 4 ratingbars. (I use the ratingbar package from pub.dev)

When you set a rating on these ratingbars the value of the rating is saved into a variable. 
Now I have a ratingbar indicator on the same screen and i want that this indicator shows the average rating of the 4 ratingbars above. I tried that the indicator shows the 4 variables divided by 4 but in that case the indicator doesn’t update if i change the rating on one of the 4 ratingbars…

so i want the indicator to listen in “realtime” if the variables change and then show a different rating… how is that possible?
I hope someone understand my problem and is able to help :)
Greetings, Yoqora

Comment: I can't find "ratingbar" at pub.dev. Is it: "rating_bar". If so, Flutter works with variables state changes. You pass the value to your rating bar and then, when you update the value, use "setState" to change it. Normally those libraries have a listener if is user interactive.

Comment: add the code whatever you tried.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla yeah you're right its rating_bar. And your solution works perfect, i didn't know about setState yet, thank you very much :)